# white space overshadowing the bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

There is a white space or border or padding which is overshadowing my navbar in my bootstrap template.

I checked for the padding and border and made it 0 but it the white space does not away?

I even tried the chrome inspect but it only points me to navbar but nothing changes when I change the parameters inside it. [image]

Any ideas on where else I should check.

this is the link of the template which I am using to tweak and customize. I am hosting the page using Laravel PHP. When I open the html file it is perfectly fine, but when I look launch it in blade format for the Laravel that's when I have the issue

https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/new-age/

Comment: You need to tell us your blade view. We are not fortune-tellers.

Comment: Could you send us the link to your blade view? Or post your blade code?

Comment: Since the same code works fine in an html file, I'd suggest checking to make sure nothing else in your blade file is being added.  If nothing else is being added there, check the parent blade file(s) for anything with padding or margin all the way up to the base blade file.